How to remove a file from storage when delete a record from database by cacasdeOnDelete by laravel
I got two database table like this
Schema::create('folders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignId('parent_id')->nullable()->constrained('folders')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('path')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('path')->nullable();
            $table->string('size');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('image_url')->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('folder_id')->nullable()->constrained('folders')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Now when I delete a folder and, in that folder, have a file so I want to remove a file when a folder root is removed. File is I upload from PC but folder just create by link does not create a physical folder in PC. I try to use Model Event but I not really understand it.

deleting a row of data from the database does not delete them from your storage. You would need to delete them using Storage facade unlink or rmdir

Does this answer your question? Laravel 5.4: how to delete a file stored in storage/app

I suggest that before you delete the file/folder data from your database, use the path to find and delete files and or folder

You should listen to the deleted model event and schedule a queue command to delete from Cloud providers.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#generating-job-classes
You cannot do a mass delete for example ->where('type' = 'redund)->delete(); in this case, you must call the models ->delete() method for each model. You need to do this because when using the mass delete, the events will not be fired.
BTW: If you are using local storage (single server), then straight "unlink()" would do. You can skip scheduling altogether.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/events
See the deleted event:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#events-using-closures
Hope that helps,
Cheers, Juha
